# ORACLE SQL - TIME DIFFERENCE

Tags: sql, oracle

i'm trying to get the minutes difference between some hours/minutes columns in Oracle SQL

```
TO_DATE((resolved_hour || ':' || resolved_minute),'HH24:M1')-TO_DATE((reported_hour || ':' || repoted_minute),'HH24:MI') as REPORTED
```

this is the code have come up with

the raw data is

```
TO_DATE((resolved_hour || ':' || resolved_minute),'HH24:M1')AS RESOLVED
```

= 14:45

```
TO_DATE((reported_hour || ':' || repoted_minute),'HH24:MI') as REPORTED
```

= 14:30

so i would expect 15 as the output.

however i'm getting

```
0.0104166666666666666666666666666666666667
```

can anyone advise of how i can achieve this?

there are seperate hour/minute columns for both.

any help would be great

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Oracle, the difference between two dates is expressed in days. Or, in this case, as the fraction of a day.

If you multiply `0.0104166666666666666666666666666666666667` by `24 * 60`, you get... something close to `15`.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use arithmetic?

```
select (resolved_hour - reported_hour) * 60 + (resolved_minute - reported_minute)
```